# PHP List function when response is in multiline or single

Tags: php, regex, list, preg-match

I use CURL method to post and receive response from the SMS aggregator.

```
$url = "https://www.smsgatewaycenter.com/library/send_sms_2.php?".$request;
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);    
list ($status, $returnmobileno, $statusdetails) = split('\|', $curl_scraped_page);
```

Now my aggregator gives response in single when I send single SMS like this

```
 $curl_scraped_page = "success | 919********** | 659613958369444158-117942947553648183"; //THIS IS EXAMPLE
```

So I use list function to get unique id `659613958369444158` before the hyphen. I am all good until I get a single response but when I get response as under, am not able to get the first unique id from the response.

**Multiline Response**

```
 success | 917*********| 3287615453600499019-106346209426268709 
 success | 919********* | 3287615453600499019-483762398162272572 
 success | 9196********** | 3287615453600499019-204615952244351373
```

**Or Single Line Multi Response**

```
success | 917*********| 3287615453600499019-106346209426268709 success | 919********* | 3287615453600499019-483762398162272572 success | 9196********** | 3287615453600499019-204615952244351373
```

From above given multi-line or single line multi response. I just need to catch `success/error` and `3287615453600499019` and store it in my DB.

Somehow lost it even with `preg_match()`.

How should I be able to achieve it?, I finally gave up after trying for 3 hours and seeking help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/(\d+)-/` should work just fine to put the desired number into a [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
<?php
$str = "success | 917*********| 3287615453600499019-106346209426268709 success | 919********* | 3287615453600499019-483762398162272572 success | ";
if (preg_match("/(success|error) \|.*?\| (\d+)-(\d+)/", $str, $matches)) {
    echo "$matches[1] - $matches[2]";
} else {
    // no match
}
```

Output:

```
3287615453600499019
```

Comment: Sorry, I was editing my question only, I need to catch success too.

Comment: Now, I added like this. Am getting the result, but can you tell me is it correct? `list ($status, $returnmobileno, $statusdetails) = split('\|', $str);
echo $status."<br>". $returnmobileno."<br>". $statusdetails."<br>";
$result = preg_match("/(\d+)\-/", $statusdetails, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);`

Comment: I suppose it would, did you try it? You don't need extra backslashes in the regular expression.

Comment: Yes, I removed extra backslash as I was trying to get from single regex. This is the output of above `success 
917*********
3287615453600499019-106346209426268709 success 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
3287615453600499019`

Comment: Your question was about getting the first number before the hyphen. That's what my answer addresses. I don't know what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I also wanted the first parameter `success`, provider if he gives error then i need to update my DB accordingly. But still thank you for your help and accepting your answer. If you come across to do it with single regex, please let me know.

Comment: Sorry, missed that part of the question. See updates.